# Problem with multi-dimensional Integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

---

[image]

---

I was learning about multi-dimensional integration when I came across this example.

Did the author of this example make a mistake at the second integration because the way I see it we get :

$$\int_0^1 \left[ 6xy  +2xy^2 + \frac{2}{3}xy^3 + 2y\right]^3_{y=0}dx$$

$$\int_0^1 \left[ 6*3x  +2x(3^2) + \frac{2}{3}x(3^3) + 2*3\right]^3_{y=0}dx$$

$$\int_0^1 \left[ 18x  + 18x + 18x + 6\right]^3_{y=0}\space dx$$

$$\int_0^1 \left(44x +6\right) dx$$

Comment: The is a mistake on the second line of the author's work: It should be $\frac23 y^3$ for the third term.

Comment: What you're doing would have been fine, but the mistake was made earlier: there shouldn't have been a factor $x$ in that third term; it is introduced accidentally/erroneously in the author's second line.

Comment: I see it now too, I was too focused on third and fourth line, thank you